# Не переведено сообщение о назначении награды

Tags: дефект, локализация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/675742/revisions

Comment: О проблеме [уже известно на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296816/339911). Надо как-то подстегнуть разработчиков. Это актуально не только для ruSO, но и для всех локализованных сайтов.